# In JMeter how to map input files with output

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter , want to provide 100 different files for 100 users  I used jp@gc - Directory Listing Data Source for providing different input files. Here we create two requests first request for accessing files and performing operations and the second request for download these output files making 100 output folder.So here 100 users use 100 random files so how to calculate which user uses which input file and where is the output file. how to map these two input and output

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) in order to get the number of current virtual use
2. Input file name you have already as the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) coming from the Directory Listing Config
3. Output file name can be configured using [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) using the values from point 1 and 2

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)